# std::map<> or std::vector<> when dealing with large sets of flags?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I am working on a compiler and have a large set of flags. In most cases, my nodes will receive a very small number of flags (about 12 for the largest), but the total number of flags is rather large (over 50.) All the flags are integers defined in an enum:

```
enum flags_t
{
    FLAG_ONE,
    FLAG_TWO,
    FLAG_THREE,
    [...]
    MAX_FLAG
};
```

I am thinking that using an `std::map<flags_t, bool>` makes more sense because most of my nodes are likely to use 0, 1, or 2 flags and the number of nodes is really large (it can easily become tenth of thousands.)

```
// with a map we have to check the existing on a get to avoid creating
// useless entries in the map
bool node::get_flag(flags_t const f)
{
    flag_iterator it(f_flags.find(f));
    return it == f_flags.end() ? false : *it;
}

void node::set_flag(flags_t const f, bool const value)
{
    f_flags[f] = value;
}
```

But I'm wondering whether `std::vector<bool>` would not actually end up being more effective? Although at first sight this looks good:

```
bool node::get_flag(flags_t const f)
{
    return f_flags[f];
}

void node::set_flag(flags_t const f, bool const value)
{
    f_flags[f] = value;
}
```

The vector needs to be allocated (i.e. sized properly) on initialization or the get_flag() functions needs to test whether f is part of the vector:

```
bool node::get_flag(flags_t const f)
{
    return f >= f_flags.size() ? false : f_flags[f];
}
```

The problem I can see with a resize() call is that we would allocate / free memory all the time, even if we end up never actually using the vector (most nodes don't need any flags!) So testing the limit when we do a get is probably a good trade off, but we also need to make sure that the vector is large enough on the set_flag() call... (in which case we'd probably allocate the whole set of flags at once to avoid reallocations.)

```
bool node::set_flag(flags_t const f, bool const value)
{
    if(MAX_FLAG > f_flags.size())
    {
        f_flags.resize(MAX_FLAG);
    }
    f_flags[f] = value;
}
```

So... would `std::vector` or `std::map` be better? Or would possibly `std::set` be even better? (I have not used std::set before...)

Comment: The upside of using bits is that you can use bitwise operations to check all flags at once.

Comment: std::vector<bool> ? => std::bitset

Comment: @smoothware Well, they use one bit per bool at least. I was imagining some C-style stuff though. Something like the first answer.

Answer (score 4):

Both `std::set` and `std::map` are a suboptimal choice for flags because they allocate storage dynamically, causing unnecessary fragmentation.

A simple way to represent flags is by storing them in an integral type. An unsigned 64-bit type will provide room for 64 flags. This will be both space-efficient and CPU-efficient, and idiomatic C++ to boot. For example:

```
enum flag_code
{
    FLAG_ONE = 1ULL << 0,
    FLAG_TWO = 1ULL << 1,
    FLAG_THREE = 1ULL << 2,
    [...]
};

typedef uint64_t flags_t;

void node::set_flag(flag_code f, bool value)
{
    if (value)
        f_flags |= f;
    else
        f_flags &= ~f;
}

bool node::get_flag(flag_code f)
{
    return bool(f_flags & f);
}
```

If more than 64 flags are needed, the bit manipulation is best left expressed with `std::bitset`, which also offers array-like access to individual bits of the underlying value:

```
enum flag_code
{
    FLAG_ONE,
    FLAG_TWO,
    FLAG_THREE,
    [...]
    MAX_FLAG
};

typedef std::bitset<MAX_FLAG - 1> flags_t;

void node::set_flag(flag_code f, bool value)
{
    f_flags[f] = value;
}

bool node::get_flag(flag_code f)
{
    return f_flags[f];
}
```

Comment: I have more than 64 bits, although I can group them and each group does not even have over 16 bits (although that could grow with time), for *security* reasons (i.e. to avoid bugs) I do not want any overlap. That way if I check the wrong flag, I get an error instead of some random result that has nothing to do with what the software is expected to do. But the bitset is probably the best solution.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Your question states that the total number of bits is "over 50", which gave the impression of being below 64. I've now updated the answer.

Comment: You are correct! I do not know the exact number, but it will likely go over 64. I am thinking to combine the flags and the attributes (which are also flags) in one set and that means I'll go over 64. Thank you for the update, that will help me as I have not used `std::bitset` before.